# Is there a way to determine in Android if an Activity's content view has been created/displayed?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

At the very beginning of my app I load up some Fragments in tabs. Here is one that I load:

```
WishlistFragment wishlistfragment = new WishlistFragment();
```

Once the Fragment has been loaded and displayed, I will be calling this from other Fragments:

```
wishlistfragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is, if I call this BEFORE the wishlistfragment is ever created/displayed, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created.

Is there a way, programmatically, to determine if a view has been created yet?

Comment: I really really really really really really recommend better encapsulation. `WishlistFragment` should have some method that the activity calls, where that method handles `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: IMHO, the activity should neither know nor care about the inner workings of the fragment (and vice versa, for that matter).

Comment: Makes sense. Since you've helped me countless times on here I will take your advice. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in way, but you could devise your own by making a method to handle the notification and overriding `onCreateView` in your `WishlistFragment`.  Something like this might work:

```
public class WishlistFragment extends ListFragment {
    private boolean _viewExists = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle )
    {
        _viewExists = true
        return super.onCreateView( inflater, container, bundle );
    }

    public void notifyChange()
    {
        if ( _viewExists )
            getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: You probably can do it even simpler, if `WishlistFragment` is a `ListFragment` -- just check to see if `getListAdapter()` returns `null` or not, and skip `notifyDataSetChanged()` if it is `null`.

Comment: CommonsWare - Your answer fixed it the quickest and easiest way, thanks.